# My element won't update display after action dispatch in my drum app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm building a React/Redux drum app and the last component I need to get working is an element that updates with the id of the selected object via action dispatch. I don't understand why it won't update the element even though I can confirm that the actions will log the id when I pass it in as a property.

My codesandbox link is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/k29r3928z7

The element is `<div id="display">{display}</div>`

And the action is

```
export const drumHit = (url, id) => {
  const sound = new Audio(url);
  sound.play();
  console.log(id);

  return {
    type: "HIT",
    id
  };
};
```

and here's the reducer:

```
const switchReducer = (state = { value: "Hello", display: "" }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SWITCH":
      return { ...state, value: action.value };

    case "HIT":
      return { ...state, display: action.id };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Any help getting this up would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sandbox:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  switcheroo: val => dispatch(switcheroo(val)),
  drumHit: id => dispatch(drumHit(id))
});
```

You aren't giving `url` parameter to your `drumHit()` action in your `mapDispatchToProps`, so `id` which is the second parameter in the definition receives `undefined`.

Additionally, your `handleKeyPress` method:

```
handleKeyPress = event => {
    const drumKey = drumObj.find(obj => obj.keyCode === event.keyCode);

    if (drumKey) {
      drumHit(drumKey.url, drumKey.id);
    }
  };
```

Is using the imported `drumHit` directly as opposed to from `this.props` which means the action won't actually be dispatched for your reducers. This is why the `console` shows the expected `id` when you play by key presses though, as both the `url` and `id` are passed.

EDIT:

Your `mapStateToProps` is using `state.id`, but your reducer is setting `id` to `display`, so you just need to change it to:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  value: state.value,
  url: state.url,
  display: state.display
});
```

Comment: I changed both of those things, and the display element still isn't changing. I saved the sandbox, what am I missing?

Comment: Also, I thought that was the point of doing this: `const { value, switcheroo, drumHit, display } = this.props;` but now it says drumHit is defined but never used

Comment: your use of it in the callback with just `drumHit` was fine, as it had come from `this.props`

Comment: Very much appreciated!